# RabbitMQ: similar queues in different exchanges

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Can I have two queues with the same name and same routingKey yet each bound to another exchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that, unless those queues are in different vhosts.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have two queues with the same name at all, (well you can if they're in different virtual hosts but I don't think that's what you're talking about).

However, you can bind one queue to many exchanges, or to one exchange with many routing keys. If you're aiming to have a single consumer pick up messages from several exchanges, that's what you want to do.